# Analyzing a function's domain

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Given the function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x-8}$$ and the question: What is the domain of $f(x)$ I would normally look for values which $f(x)$ can not take.

So I would check for plus infinity...Well $f(x)$ is defined positively for plus infinity...It is defined negatively for negative infinity and it is defined for 0 too...So I'm having a hard time finding a $f(x)$ which it can not take...I forgot how to do these, can anyone tell me how I analyze the domain of $f(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to consider any/all $x$-values at which $f(x)$ is not defined.

What happens if $x = 8$?

---

Note: After re-reading your post and your comments below, I think you are confusing the "range" (image) of the function with it's *domain.*

Loosely speaking:

The domain of a function is the set of all values that $x$ can take on, and consists of all and only those $x$ for which $f(x)$ is defined.

The range of a function deals with the resultant "outputs" $f(x)$ when evaluated at each $x$ in the function's domain. This is the set $\{f(x)\mid x \in \text{ Domain }\}$

Comment: Then $f(x)$ is not defined.

So the limit as $x$ approaches $8$ does not exist either? I think I am just getting a bit confused with things.

Comment: No, it happens not to exist. Approaching $8$ from the left, $f(x) \to -\infty$, and from the right, $f(x) \to +\infty$. At any rate, the domain consists of all real number *excluding* $8$.

Comment: So the definition for a limit not existing is that it gives two different outcomes as we approach from each side?

Comment: That is one way in which the limit does not exist. There are others, as well.

Comment: Hold on, now I remember where my confusion stems from:

So we say that $x$ can not take on the value $8$. So...For what values is the function defined? I know it's not defined for some value where $x$ is 8...But what value is that?

What would be the actual domain?

Comment: You need to look at the domain: The domain is the set of all values that $x$ can take on, so that the function is defined. The range of a function deals with the resultant values that $f(x)$ takes on, when evaluated for all elements in the function's domain.

Comment: The domain is the set of all valid "x" values. A function's range (or image) is the set of all "y = f(x)" values under the function's domain. Domain: valid input values, Range/Image: outputs corresponding to valid inputs.

Comment: Then I am confusing range with domain. I am thinking of range. Should I make a new question?

Comment: Yes, why not post a separate question. The range will be all real numbers, excluding $0$. $f(x) = \frac 1{x-8}$ will never evaluate to zero, for any $x$. Why not graph the function to get some intuition?

Answer (score 1):

The domain is $(-\infty, 8) \cup (8, \infty)$, or equivalently, $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{8\}$. Note that the function is well-defined for all real numbers besides $8$. Often the first tactic one should take in determining the domain for these types of functions (fractional) is to set the denominator equal to zero and solve for its roots. Here, we have $$x - 8 = 0 \implies x=8$$
is a root of the denominator of $f(x)$, and thus a discontinuity of the function (so not included in its domain).